# Divide by zero error with scikits.statsmodels.api in summary

Tags: python-2.7, statsmodels

I am building an OLS regression model and I wanted to make a small test (given below).  I create the input data fine and when I tell the model to fit it goes through but when I ask for the summary I get a divide by zero error.  Here is some code (I've swapped out actual data for random calls here)

```
import numpy
import scikits.statsmodels.api as sm

y = numpy.random.randn(10)
x = numpy.random.randn(10, 18)

x = sm.add_constant(x, prepend=True)

model = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
model.summary() #CREATES DIVIDE BY ZERO ERROR
```

In the traceback the divide by zero occurs in linear_model.pyc

```
@cache_readonly
def rsquared_adj(self):
    return 1 - (self.nobs - 1)/sef.df_resid * (1 - self.rsquared)
@cache_readonly
```

Comment: where are self.df_resid and self.rsquared coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example there are more variables (columns) in x than observations (rows). As a consequence you have a perfect fit. None of the result statistics make any statistical sense in this case.

The zero division error in rsquared_adj occurs since df_resid is zero.

summary() is calling some attributes and methods that raise the exception. You will also get similar exceptions when you call any of those attributes yourself.

I think statsmodels should raise a proper informative exception in this case, instead of letting it break at some arbitrary points.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in master. Now, summary() will simply print nan.

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/868